# Replacing more than one word with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace some text:

My text looks like:

Magna adipisicing veniam est amet labore do mollit deserunt esse. Ipsum minim sit [[consectetur qui consequat]] elit id irure. Occaecat magna do voluptate commodo veniam nulla adipisicing.

I want to replace the text inside [[...]]. The problem is that if there are more words between the brackets, it won't render.

This is my current Regex:

```
"/\[\[(\w+)\]\]/"
```

Comment: If you want to match words without leading or trailing spaces and 1 space in between `\[\[(\w+(?: \w+)*)\]\]`

Comment: You just use the wildcard to match all characters in between the brackets:

`\[\[(.*)\]\]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\d` does not match any white spaces. Try

```
"/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/“
```

(Not tested)

I added the `?` ( non greedy) in case you have more than one case to match.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a *"mystery text"* with one asterisk for each letter between the double square brackets, you can use this pattern with `preg_replace()`:

```
$pattern = '~(?: \G (?!\A) | \[\[ (?= [^]]* ]] ) ) \s* \K [^]\s]~x';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, '*', $str);
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/oedH5)

For one asterisk per word, just add the `+` quantifier to the last character class.

Otherwise, if you want only one asterisk for all the content, Sil's answer is the good one (eventually with the s modifier).